# How to get the system date and time using socket programming

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I sending simple message from client to the server here and its working fine, But what if client wants to fetch the server system date and time.

```
Client
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
Client::Client(QObject* parent): QObject(parent)
{
    connect(&client, SIGNAL(connected()),
    this, SLOT(startTransfer()));
}

Client::~Client()
{
    client.close();
}

void Client::start(QString address, quint16 port)
{
    QHostAddress addr(address);
    client.connectToHost(addr, port);
}

void Client::startTransfer()
{
    client.write("Hi server this is client", 80);
}
```

I don't have any idea how to do that as i am new in QT c++. thank you so much in advance ...

```
server
```

main.cpp

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
  #include <QApplication>



  int main(int argc, char** argv)
  {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Server server;
    return app.exec();
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean the *local* systems date and time? Or that of the *remote* system?

Comment: client could not get server time, you have to send it with your packet.   `QDateTime dateTime = dateTime.currentDateTime();` and 
    `QString dateTimeString = dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss");`

Comment: Reading your comments, it seems that you want to implement a *protocol*. Just sending arbitrary data trough a connected socket doesn't mean anything, you have to *add meaning* to the data you send.

Comment: I agree with @Some programmer dude if you have request/response with server and clients you have to need a protocol. but if you only have this issue do the current way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this part of code you released is client side  , you should provide a request from client to server like common hand shaking.

In server side you provide the date/time in a specific format that client can recognize it and send it. to seem more on client/server programming check [Local Fortune Client](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-ipc-localfortuneclient-example.html) and [Local Fortune Server](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-ipc-localfortuneserver-example.html) examples.

here is your client side simple example:

```
void Client::startTransfer()
{
    client.write("Hi server send time");
    client.flush();
    client.waitForBytesWritten(300);
}
```

and you server side example :

on `newconnection` slot in server connect client data to a slot like client message.

```
void ServerSocket::newConnection()
{
    QTcpSocket *clientsocket = mserver->nextPendingConnection();
    connect(clientsocket , SIGNAL(readyRead()) , this , SLOT(clientMessage()));
}
```

and respond it in slot client message

```
void ServerSocket::clientMessage()
{
    QTcpSocket* client = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
    QString  message(client->readAll());
    if (message == "Hi server send time")
    {
        client->write(QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc().toString().toLatin1());
        client->flush();
        client->waitForBytesWritten(300);
    }
}
```

here is a complete code requested :

> servesocket.h

```
#ifndef SERVERSOCKET_H
#define SERVERSOCKET_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>

class ServerSocket : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ServerSocket(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    QTcpServer *mserver;

signals:

public slots:

    void newConnection();
    void clientMessage();

};

#endif // SERVERSOCKET_H
```

> serversocket.cpp

```
#include "serversocket.h"
#include <QDateTime>

ServerSocket::ServerSocket(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    mserver = new QTcpServer(this);
    mserver->connect(mserver , SIGNAL(newConnection()) , this , SLOT(newConnection()));
    if(!mserver->listen(QHostAddress::Any , 1234))
    {
        qDebug() << "Server initilize failed";
    }
}

void ServerSocket::newConnection()
{
    QTcpSocket *clientsocket = mserver->nextPendingConnection();
    connect(clientsocket , SIGNAL(readyRead()) , this , SLOT(clientMessage()));
}

void ServerSocket::clientMessage()
{
    QTcpSocket* client = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
    QString  message(client->readAll());
    if (message == "Hi server send time")
    {
        client->write(QDateTime::currentDateTimeUtc().toString().toLatin1());
        client->flush();
        client->waitForBytesWritten(300);
    }
}
```

> MainWindow header

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QSerialPort>

#include "serversocket.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);//:QMainWindow(parent)
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:



private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    ServerSocket * server;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

> MainWindow cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    server = new ServerSocket();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: @explorer104 if you want a complete code, I will send you one

Comment: yes please, i need the complete code. thank you so much

Comment: @explorer104 I added server header/cpp files, it's just a simple server demonstrate client message request. if you have any further questions please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: I suggest you first read examples i mentioned in answer carefully and understand it then code. It may cost you less time to code first and learn then.

Comment: thank you so much. can you send me the server main.cpp code . it doesn't show anything here.

Comment: therer is nothing special but, i added to answer . if this post helps you can mark it as answer or upvote.

Comment: What's your problem with it. I've tested this code and works fine, you should mention any errors you got.

Comment: I will add mainwindow header and you will find it to correct

Comment: Give me your email to send you whole project

Comment: @explorer104 I am waiting for your email.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get server system date/time from client.

you  have to send it as packet.

```
void Client::startTransfer()
{
    QDateTime dateTime = dateTime.currentDateTime(); 
    QString dateTimeString = dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss");
    // send "dateTimeString" here
}
```

Comment: @explorer104 you have to send date/time your self. send date/time on first connection and server & client could be sync together.  or send a packet request and to get date/time.

Comment: thank you. now how the server will response back to the client for the packet we sent just now.?

Comment: @explorer104 client send his request for example `client.write("Req_Date_time");` and server receive it and make sure it's correct and send date/time back like it my answer.